# innerHTML error in syntax not working; Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')

Tags: javascript, html, syntax-error, innerhtml

For some reason I am keep on getting a syntax error from this "innerHTML", can someone help me?

HTML CODE:

```
<div id="ID"></div>
```

JavaScript CODE:

```
document.getElementById("ID").innerHTML = "Test";
```

Syntax Error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')

I am trying to make the div respond with a "Test" using "innerHTML" and "getElementById" but the syntax error is getting in the way.

Comment: The error means that `document.getElementById("ID")` isn't returning a reference to a DOM object, so there's nothing to set the `innerHTML` of.

Comment: Please also provide the HTML code you're using. Tip: don't use "ID" as and ID, instead use something more specific, such as id="left-sidebar". And make sure the ID is unique.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that js not found with the selector ID. You need ID as a selector. Take a look:

```js
document.getElementById("ID").innerHTML = "Test";
```

```html
<div id="ID">Hello</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error refers to the fact that `document.getElementById("ID")` is invalid. Meaning that "ID" is not existing. In your HTML code there needs to be an object with the `id="ID"`.

Answer (score 0):

Running getElementById on an ID that isn't currently existing on the webpage will give you this error, if you are working on a project with multiple scenes and you try to call this for an element on a scene that is NOT currently shown on the screen it will error out with this error.